# Verify that $ y(x) = Ae^{2x} + Be^{-2x} - 2\cos(x) - 5x\sin(x) $ is a solution of the ODE for any value of the constants A and B.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that
$ y(x) = Ae^{2x} + Be^{-2x} - 2\cos(x) - 5x\sin(x) $
is a solution of the ordinary differential equation
$ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 4y = 25x\sin(x) $
for any value of the constants A and B. $\\$

I seem to have differentiated correctly, so I'm unsure of why my reasoning is incorrect. Please explain why my reasoning is incorrect and how I can reason about this correctly to get the correct solution. Thank you.

My reasoning is as follows:

We must first find the second derivative of $y(x)$. We can then substitute this into the ODE to check if it is a solution. $\\$

$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2Ae^{2x} - 2Be^{-2x} + 2\sin(x) - 5\sin(x) - 5x\cos(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

$ \Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2Ae^{2x} - 2Be^{-2x} - 3\sin(x) - 5x\cos(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

$ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 4Ae^{2x} + 4Be^{-2x} - 3\cos(x) - 5\cos(x) + 5x\sin(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

$ \Rightarrow \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 4Ae^{2x} + 4Be^{-2x} - 8\cos(x) + 5x\sin(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

We now substitute the second derivative into the ODE. $\\[5pt]$

$ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 4y = 25x\sin(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

$ 4Ae^{2x} + 4Be^{-2x} - 8\cos(x) + 5x\sin(x) - 4y = 25x\sin(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

$ \Rightarrow 4Ae^{2x} + 4Be^{-2x} - 8\cos(x) - 4y = 20x\sin(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

We can now verify if this is a solution. Let $A = 2$, $B = 3$, $ x = 1 $, $ y = 4 $. $\\$

$ 4(2)e^{2(1)} + 4(3)e^{-2(1)} - 8\cos(1) - 4(4) = 20(1)\sin(1) $ $\\[5pt]$

$ \Rightarrow 8e^{2} + 12e^{-2} - 8\cos(1) - 16 = 20(1)\sin(1) $ $\\[5pt]$

Which is false.

My error was in not substituting $y$. My corrected solution is as follows.

$ \Rightarrow 4Ae^{2x} + 4Be^{-2x} - 8\cos(x) -  4Ae^{2x} - 4Be^{-2x} + 8cos(x) + 20x\sin(x) = 20x\sin(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

$ \Rightarrow 20x\sin(x) = 20x\sin(x) $ $\\[5pt]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must substitute $Ae^{2x}+Be^{-2x}-2\cos x-5x\sin x$ instead of $y$ in the equation just before 'We can now verify if this is a solution'.

Comment: This makes sense. I seemed to have forgotten this part of the computation.

Answer (score 2):

Your "let $x=1$, $y=4$" part is wrong. There seems to be confusion about what is a solution to an ODE.

Consider a simpler equation. 
$$
y'=2x\tag{1} 
$$
Then 
$
y(x)=x^2+C
$
is a solution to (1) for any constant $C$. What would happen if you arbitrarily pick $x$, $y$ and $C$, say $x=0$, $y=2016$, $C=\pi$?

---

In general, suppose you have a first order ODE
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=F(y,x)\tag{2}
$$
What does mean by $y=g(x)$ is a solution to (2)? It means
$$
g'(x)=F(g(x),x).
$$

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The second part doesn't make sense. You've said it much more eloquently than I have: "...it is another function which satisfies the differential equation". Your reasoning is clearer to me now. Thanks!